# Accessing parent object from child object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three serializers, nested within each other. Like this:

```
class PersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id :name
  has_many: companies

   class Company < ActiveModel::Serializer
    has_many :products

     class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      has_many :product_items do
        unless person.id != object.company.user_id
          object.product_items
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My issue is the line: `unless person.id != object.company.user_id`.
person is undefined here. How do I get access to the current `person` instance within the ProductSerializer?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why would you need that structure, but general `class` definition declares a new scope. Whether you need to capture variables from the parent scope, use closure with [`Class#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-c-new) instead:

```
class PersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id :name
  has_many: companies

  Company = Class.new(ActiveModel::Serializer) do
    has_many :products

     ProductSerializer = Class.new(ActiveModel::Serializer) do
      has_many :product_items do
        unless person.id != object.company.user_id
          object.product_items
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```